# Send data in chunks using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets, printwriter

I just build a web solution which uploads an excel file and adds the records to a database.

For every successful record it returns this message:

```
<tr>
    <td>item.getString(Id)+</td>
    <td>item.getString(Nombre)+</td>
    <td><a href='mailto:item.getString(Email)+'>item.getString(Email)+</a></td>
    <td>item.getMap(CADI).size()+</td>
    <td>Success</td>
    </tr>;
```

For every unsuccessful record it returns this message:

```
<tr>
    <td>item.getString(Id)+</td>
    <td>item.getString(Nombre)+</td>
    <td><a href='mailto:item.getString(Email)+'>item.getString(Email)+</a></td>
    <td>item.getMap(CADI).size()+</td>
    <td>Fail to Upload</td>
    </tr>;
```

My problem is that I´m using an Ajax request which process the request and append this result to a existing table. Data is visible ones the entire process is finished. Is their a way to print results as soon as the data is added to database?

I´m using JSP and here is my AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url :<%="'" + getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/GetInfo'"%>,
    data:{
        m1:id,
        m2:nombre,
        m3:email,
        m4:cadi,
        m5:conferencia
    },
    datatype:"text",
    success : function(response) {
        $("#table-content").append(response);                           
        $("html").css("cursor", "default");
        $("button").css("cursor", "default");
    }
});
```

And this is what I use to return my values using Java and Servlets.

```
public void printItem(PrintWriter out, AVLNode r){
   if (r != null)
       {
           printItem(out,r.left);  
           Item item=new Item()
                .withPrimaryKey("Id",r.id+"")
                .withString("Nombre",r.nombre)
                .withString("Email",r.email)
                .withMap("CADI", r.data);
            String obj=db.addItem("Contactos",item); //This is where the message is printed
            out.println(obj);
            out.flush();
            printItem(out,r.right);  
        }
    }
}
```

Additional information: I´m using an AVLTree to sort data and print it.

### Thanks

Comment: Are you adding all the "records" as one single database transaction?

Comment: No they are multiple transactions in order to assure I´m getting separate message results.

Comment: I'm not sure you want multiple database transactions here.  If a failure occurs, how will be able to easily handle rollbacks?  Most client side webapps just display a loading message.

Comment: I´m quite aware that it´s not the best practice but is an explicit requirement  to show how data is processed. In case an Item fails to upload the program will just "skip it", commit is done as soon as the data is received in the server. Their are no rollbacks

Comment: Here are two keywords: poll, push.

Comment: @BalusC can you show an example please?